# If a user doesn't have permission to render a View (configured on configure.zcml), how do I raise Forbidden instead of redirecting to login_form?

Tags: plone

I have a browser view, with some utilities. Is mainly an "utility view" that I traverse using old-style pt templates (that are inside `skins` folder). My `browser/configure.zcml`:

```
  <browser:page
      for="*"
      name="my_view"
      class=".myview.MyView"
      allowed_interface=".myview.IMyView"
      permission="my.permission"
      />
```

As you can see, it has a custom permission: this is needed because anonymous users can't render this view and this permission is really specific to a certain situation in my portal.

I thought: I'm going to try to render the view in my `template.pt`: since I've already set a permission in `browser/configure.zcml`, when trying to render Plone itself is going to handle this for me. So I did in my template

```
    <span tal:define="my_view here/@@myview">
    </span>
```

So far, so good. A user without `my.permission` trying to get into `/Plone/template.pt` will fail. But Plone redirects to the login form, and I would prefer to raise a Forbidden exception instead. Something like:

```
    <span tal:define="my_view here/@@myview | here/raiseForbidden">
    </span>
```

...but, of course, this doesn't work since the view rendering didn't throw an error. (I know here/raiseForbidden doesn't exist, it's here/raiseUnauthorized that is usually used but the concept is the same)

My question is: is it possible to do it? Configuring my permission somewhere, or configuring some method in my view (like `render` or `__call__`), that when a user doesn't have permission to render it, [an exception like `Forbidden` is raised](http://readthedocs.org/docs/collective-docs/en/latest/security/permissions.html#checking-if-the-logged-in-user-has-a-permission)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plone redirects to the login form *because* you raise Unauthorized. If you want different behaviour you'll need to do something different.

In this case, you could directly redirect the user to a new page with an error message tailored to the situation.

Comment: You're right, I want the `Forbidden` exception. Should I do @giacomos `__call__` solution then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948507/if-a-user-doesnt-have-permission-to-render-a-view-configured-on-configure-zcml/6949536#6949536 , but raising `Forbidden`?

Comment: That, or create your own raiseForbidden method based on the raiseUnauthorized script. Placing it in the view `__call__` smells a little better to me, architecture-wise.

Comment: I agree. You've even answered a similar question 2 years a go. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222880/an-easy-way-to-redirect-certain-roles-in-zope/1226761#1226761 :)

Comment: Gah, I keep forgetting about the time machine! Warning, time travel may cause side effects; including, but not limited to amnesia.

Answer (score -1):

actually you don't need to do this:

"tal:define="my_view here/@@myview>"

because for browser views there's a default variable named "view" that already contain your class.

For raising an exception you should remove permission check from the zml directive and modify your class as below:

```
from Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile import ViewPageTemplateFile
from AccessControl import getSecurityManager
from AccessControl import Unauthorized

class YourBrowserView(BrowserView):
    """ .. """
    index = ViewPageTemplateFile("templates/yourtemplate.pt")

    ...

    def __call__(self):
        if not getSecurityManager().checkPermission(your.permission, self.context):
            raise Unauthorized("You are not authorized! Go away!")
        else: return index()
```

Bye
Giacomo

Comment: `template.pt` is inside `skins` instead of `browser`. Is `ViewPageTemplateFile` capable of rendering something inside `skins` folder?

Comment: The problem isn't in the raising; that works. The question is about the redirection to the login-form.

Comment: anyway, in this case you should use traversal instead of ViewPageTemplateFile: "else: return self.context.portal_skins.custom['template.pt']()" where custom is the skin layer name where the template is. But i think you should consider using browserview/templates in the correct way