# Plone: How to enable redirection to login form for specific view for anonymous user?

Tags: view, plone, skin, plone-4.x

We are maintaining a Plone 4 site and have a special view of a folder "foo" which is only accessible for authenticated users with special roles. Authenticated users can access the view like this:

```
http://<host>:<port>/Plone/foo/@@special-view
```

However, if an anonymous user tries to access the view, an `Unauthorized` exception is thrown:

```
Unauthorized: Your user account does not have the required permission.
Access to 'macros' of (FSPageTemplate at /Plone/foo/main_template) denied.
Your user account, Anonymous User, exists at (unknown). Access requires
View_Permission, granted to the following roles: ['Extern', 'Manager',
'Member', 'Site Administrator']. Your roles in this context are
['Anonymous'].
> /home/ted/work/ps/eggs/AccessControl-2.13.13-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/
AccessControl/ImplPython.py(797)raiseVerbose()-> raise Unauthorized(text)
```

The definition of the action in `profiles/default/types/foo.xml` looks like this:

```
<action title="Special View" action_id="special-view" category="object" condition_expr=""
  url_expr="string:${object_url}/special-view" visible="True">
  <permission value="Modify portal content" />
</action>
```

**How can we achieve that anonymous users get redirected to the login page and after login redirected to the URL they originally wanted to access?**

Interestingly, this is already working for content objects that reside within folder "foo", but not for the folder itself and not for our special view.

For these objects the user gets redirected to this URL, which will show the login form and redirect to the requested page after login:

```
http://<host>:<port>/Plone/acl_users/credentials_cookie_auth/require_login?came_from=http%3A//<host>%3A<port>/Plone/foo/@@special-view
```

Debugging showed us that a PAS challenge is made in these cases but we don't know how to enable this feature for our special view.

**UPDATE 2016-06-23**

I added this `<browser:page` definition to `configure.zcml`, but it didn't change anything:

```
  <browser:page
      name="new-members"
      for="cnrd.vctypes.interfaces.ICnrdMemberFolder"
      class=".behaviors.cnrd_member_folder.ShowNewMembers"
      permission="cmf.ModifyPortalContent"
  />
```

Comment: Can you give us your corresponding `<browser:page` declaration from `configure.zcml`? (That should already have a `permission` attribute.)

Comment: We have no `<browser:page` declaration in our `configure.zcml`. Only an action is defined for the folder object. This might be the cause of the problem. What kind of permission should we set?

Comment: The action-permission just defines if the action-button is provided to the user in the UI, that should be fine. What is interesting is, that you get error on the folder but not not on its children, check the permissions of its wf-state and local-roles (via sharing-tab), if they grant view-perms for anon. For forcing a redirect anyways, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222880/an-easy-way-to-redirect-certain-roles-in-zope/1226761#1226761

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error message closely, it looks like you're calling a macro, located in a skin-folder, of a browser-based view.
The docs give a hint for the cause and how you can let the error gracefully fail, here:
http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/security/permissions.html?highlight=unauthorized#catching-unauthorized

Or, try to retrieve the error-throwing variable with other ("oldskool"-)methods, which not ask for ZOPE-admin permissions, even before reaching the login-form.

Another (my preferred) possibility is, to exchange the skin-template with a browser-template, as described in the "Views"-chapter of the docs, and here's also an example for illustration purposes (disclaiming one of my unpublished addons):
https://github.com/ida/adi.forumail/tree/master/adi/forumail/browser/resources